# Using bindElement to navigate to next page.But the onAfterRendering method of the list in Next page is not triggering in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5, event-delegation

I am using a NavContainer which has two pages. The first page has a list on clicking the list item I am navigating to a second page which has a list but binding data is based on the currently clicked item in the first page. while navigating to a second page I am using **bindElement** method.In this, I am passing clicked item path and binding the second-page elements according to the path. But this second page has a list and I have added **onAfterRendering** event delegate like this,

```
secondPageList.addEventDelegate({onAfterRendering:myfunction},this);
```

But **onAfterRendering** method is not getting called when ever I click on a list item in the first page and second page opens, Why?

Comment: I think you want is onBeforeShow not onAfterRendering.

Comment: Yes but onBeforeRendering is also not calling. I have tried with that also

Comment: have you tried using routeMatched/patternMatched instead?

Comment: No, actually the binding path will change every time. It depends on the item clicked in the first page.But in second page I am displaying same list every time and data will be changed based on clicked item

Comment: I think you are binding to wrong control. Shouldnt it be -**secondPageView**.addEventDelegate({onAfterRendering:myfunction},this); and not **secondPageList**.addEventDelegate({onAfterRendering:myfunction},this);

Comment: No actually in second page I have a list. And I am adding onAfterRendering event delegate to that list.

Answer (score 0):

onAfterRendering does not need to be added using addEventDelegate, if can just be added as a function. Same as onInit and onBeforeRendering. These **I believe** are available to all controllers.

The addEventDelegate is for items like onBeforeShow which are only available for pages (I believe).

Also have a look at Routes and more importantly onRouteMatched if you want to pass data from your Master View to your Child View.

Kind Regards,
Keith.